# php can't open more than 2 mp3 files at same time?

Tags: php, linux, flash, file, mp3

here's what i'm doing:

**"dl"** folder contains a variety of mp3 music albums archives in zip format. For this example, let's say i have an archive called "some_album.zip" and inside the zip file there is a file called "some_song.mp3

**"playlist.php"** will get the list of mp3 files inside a zip archive then build a XML file to use as playlist with a flash mp3 player.
For each mp3 entry in the xml file, it returns a filename value like this:

```
<location>mp3.php?file=some_album.zip#some_song.mp3</location>
```

**"mp3.php"** will read the file inside the zip archive (without extracting it) using *zip://some_album.zip#some_song.mp3* then it will output the content with mp3 headers.
So when i go to *mp3.php?file=some_album.zip#some_song.mp3* it will stream the mp3 file just like it was a real file.

**player.html** is just a flash mp3 player that will stream the album using "playlist.php" XML file.

**The problem** is that the flash player will only play the first 2 songs no matter what i try. It looks like the server can't open more than 2 files at same time or a maximum of X megabytes.

I triple-checked that all mp3 filenames are correct inside the XML playlist and if i manually launch the mp3 URL in my browser it will work perfectly.
The mp3 player also detects the mp3 length which confirms the filename is good.

I have also tried with 3 different mp3 players and all of them have the same problem : i am only able to play the first 2 songs. 
So my question is: could it be a setting on my dedicated server that prevent me from reading more than 2 files at same time inside the zip archive ?

Example flash player:
http://www.pirate-punk.com/player/test.html

using this XML playlist (generated from php with content of a zip archive):
http://www.pirate-punk.com/ODYgQ3JldyAtIDIwMDAgLSBCYWQgQmFkIFJlZ2dhZS56aXA=.xml

Comment: Have you actually confirmed your assumptions?  Or are they just assumptions?  Your browser is probably only making 4 connections to the server at a time.  It's possible for those media files to require 2 connections each, due to the way some browsers handle seekable media.  Actually confirm your problem is server-side before posting a question like this.  If you have done that already, please add that to your question.

Comment: how can i confirm it.... like i said i tried 3 different flash mp3 players and i can only play the first 2 songs..

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to monitor network requests.  Or better yet (in this case), use Wireshark or Fiddler.  If you only see 2-4 requests from the browser, then the issue is getting your browser to download more from the server at a time.